# SQL Join limiting left table by right

Tags: sql, join

I need to do a SQL Query where I pull users that are in Table 1 and either not in table 2 at all, or not in a specific subset of table 2.

Here is what I have:

Table ClientUsers
**ID    UserName**
1       User1
2       User2
3       User3
4       User4
5       User5

Table UserRoles
**ClientUsersID    ClientRolesID**
1                      101
2                      166
5                      103

I need to select all users that are either in UsersRoles with any ClientRoleID that is not 166 OR not in User Roles at all.

So in this case, I would select users 1, and 3-5. 1 and 5 because they are in table UserRoles with a role other than 166, and 3 and 4 because they are in table ClientUsers but NOT table UserRoles at all.

I haven't been able to use a null in the WHERE statement because then it's looking for a null value in a column, as opposed to a row that doesn't exist.

I think that I have to use a full outer join, then narrow the results, but I haven't found a query that works yet.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ClientUsers 
 FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.UserRoles on ClientUsers.ID = UserRoles.ClientUsersID  
 WHERE UserRoles.ClientRolesID != 166 OR [value not in right table]
```

I don't know how to replace that bracket with something that will work (or redo the query entirely).

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT cu.*
FROM dbo.ClientUsers cu
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.UserRoles ur
                  WHERE cu.ID = ur.ClientUsersID AND ur.ClientRolesID = 166 
                 );
```

This is almost a direct translation of your problem statement.

Comment: Nice, I was not familiar with not exists. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
 SELECT *
    FROM dbo.ClientUsers
         FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.UserRoles on ClientUsers.ID = UserRoles.ClientUsersID
  WHERE UserRoles.ClientRolesID != 166 or UserRoles.ClientRolesID is NULL;
```

Comment: I had tried that, and it didn't work for me, unfortunately. It just grabs the ones that are in the User roles table and an ID that isn't 166.